# Date displaying twice in date picker

Tags: java, android

Current date is displaying twice in my date picker android app I don't
understand why this is happening.Can anyone tell me what is causing this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);           // current year
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);         // current month
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);    // current day

    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    t1.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                }

            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

This is the image

[image]

Comment: code was crashed, after removing `datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());`, its working fine and its not showing dialog twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are facing is the manner how the date picker is implemented. Usually, the title date should go away if you use it like this:

```
datePickerDialog.setTitle("");
```

this call have to be directly before `datePickerDialog.show();`

Answer (score -1):

You need to give a "time" for the fragment to be rendered.

Try this:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000);
```